# How to make flv-players work with iphone/ipad?

Tags: video, iphone, flash

We don't want to use youtube-embedded videos on our site. How can we make our flv-player (flash) work with iphone/ipad? Is it something with the codec used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iOS (iPhone, iPad, etc) [does not support flash](http://www.apple.com/hotnews/thoughts-on-flash/) and will not do so in the near future and there is no real good way to make it run flash that would be easy for your customers to use.

I would suggest to bite the bullet and host an h.264 version of your videos on your site.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I found this site that solves everything: http://diveintohtml5.org/video.html